# Regions, Mesh Regions, and Graphics

Tags: regions, mesh, graphics

This behavior seems inconsistent to me:

```
ConicHullRegion[{{0, 0}}, {{1/3, 2/3}, {2/3, 1/3}}];
{Graphics[%], Show[%]}
ConvexHullMesh[{{0, 0}, {1/3, 2/3}, {2/3, 1/3}}];
{Graphics[%], Show[%]}
```

I would like to display these two regions in a consistent way, but I don't really understand the underlying graphical difference between the two resulting *Mathematica* objects.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region.html

Comment: My question is why are these two region have two different relationships to graphics system?  One "shows" immediately, and can't be passed to Graphics, the other requires "Graphics" to show.

Comment: A good partial answer would explain the difference between graphic objects and "showable" objects.

Comment: The only regions that auto visualize are `BoundryMeshRegion` and `MeshRegion`. `ConvexHullMesh` returns the former. Some regions can serve as graphics primitives and vice versa. `Graphics` is intended only for visualization and different directives like color, thickness, dashing, etc can be associated to primitives. Regions are simply point sets and that makes it less clear how to associate directives with certain parts. The mesh regions mentioned above are somewhat of an exception. The connectivity of mesh cells can matter in some contexts and it gives ways to associate certain directives.

Comment: Some more experimentation helped me to understand the structure better.